# Toogle Favorites in onDismissable event in Flutter with Bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I'm having some trouble completing the action related to how I should add/remove (toggle) favorites from a list(coming from an api response). Actually I'm able to add the favorite to the list and also remove it in a separated way, but I can't do it with the same button in a toggled way. In Brief, it is working but I cannot achieve the toggle action properly. Please could you take a look at the code and see if there's a good approach on how to achieve toggling without using setstate?

Button to Dismiss (delete from list)

```
CupertinoButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        minSize: 30,
                        onPressed: () {
                          onDismissed();
                        },
                        child: CircleContainer(
                          child: Icon(
                            item.isFavorite
                                ? Icons.favorite
                                : Icons.favorite_border,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          size: 35,
                        ),
                      ),
```

Same Button achieving adding favorite to list with Bloc

```
CupertinoButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        minSize: 30,
                        onPressed: () {
                          masterBloc.add(MasterAddToFavorites(item));
                        },
                        child: CircleContainer(
                          child: Icon(
                            item.isFavorite
                                ? Icons.favorite
                                : Icons.favorite_border,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          size: 35,
                        ),
                      ),
```

Item definition

```
class YoutbeVideo {
  final String videoId, title, description, banner;
  bool isFavorite;

  YoutbeVideo(
      {@required this.videoId,
      @required this.title,
      @required this.description,
      @required this.banner,
      this.isFavorite});

  void toggleFavoriteStatus() {
    isFavorite = !isFavorite;
  }
```

BloC Code divided in 3 files

master_bloc

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:documentales_app/models/youtube_video.dart';
import 'master_events.dart';
import 'master_state.dart';

class MasterBloc extends Bloc<MasterEvents, MasterState> {
  @override
  MasterState get initialState => MasterState.initialState();

  @override
  Stream<MasterState> mapEventToState(MasterEvents event) async* {
    if (event is MasterSetTab) {
      yield this.state.copyWith(currentTab: event.tab);
    } else if (event is MasterAddToHistory) {
      yield* _addToHistory(event);
    } else if (event is MasterRemoveFromHistory) {
      yield* _removeFromHistory(event);
    } else if (event is MasterRemoveFromFavorites) {
      yield* _removeFromFavorites(event);
    } else if (event is MasterLogout) {
      yield this.state.copyWith(history: [], currentTab: 0);
    } else if (event is MasterAddToFavorites) {
      yield* _addToFavorites(event);
    }
  }

  Stream<MasterState> _addToHistory(MasterAddToHistory event) async* {
    final int index = this
        .state
        .history
        .indexWhere((item) => item.videoId == event.youtubeVideo.videoId);

    if (index == -1) {
      final history = List<YoutubeVideo>.from(this.state.history);
      history.add(event.youtubeVideo);

      yield this.state.copyWith(history: history);
    }
  }

  Stream<MasterState> _addToFavorites(MasterAddToFavorites event) async* {
    final int index = this
        .state
        .favorites
        .indexWhere((item) => item.videoId == event.youtubeVideo.videoId);

    if (index == -1) {
      final favorites = List<YoutubeVideo>.from(this.state.favorites);
      favorites.add(event.youtubeVideo);

      yield this.state.copyWith(favorites: favorites);
    }
  }

  Stream<MasterState> _removeFromHistory(MasterRemoveFromHistory event) async* {
    final history = List<YoutubeVideo>.from(this.state.history);
    history.removeAt(event.index);
    yield this.state.copyWith(history: history);
  }

  Stream<MasterState> _removeFromFavorites(
      MasterRemoveFromFavorites event) async* {
    final favorites = List<YoutubeVideo>.from(this.state.favorites);
    favorites.removeAt(event.index);
    yield this.state.copyWith(favorites: favorites);
  }
}
```

master state

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart' show required;
import 'package:documentales_app/models/youtube_video.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class MasterState extends Equatable {
  final int currentTab;
  final List<YoutubeVideo> history;
  final List<YoutubeVideo> favorites;

  MasterState(
      {@required this.currentTab, @required this.history, this.favorites});

  static MasterState initialState() =>
      MasterState(currentTab: 0, history: [], favorites: []);

  MasterState copyWith(
      {int currentTab,
      List<YoutubeVideo> history,
      List<YoutubeVideo> favorites}) {
    return MasterState(
        currentTab: currentTab ?? this.currentTab,
        history: history ?? this.history,
        favorites: favorites ?? this.favorites);
  }

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [currentTab, history, favorites];
}
```

master events

```
import 'package:documentales_app/models/youtube_video.dart';

abstract class MasterEvents {}

class MasterSetTab extends MasterEvents {
  final int tab;

  MasterSetTab(this.tab);
}

class MasterAddToHistory extends MasterEvents {
  final YoutubeVideo youtubeVideo;

  MasterAddToHistory(this.youtubeVideo);
}

class MasterAddToFavorites extends MasterEvents {
  final YoutubeVideo youtubeVideo;

  MasterAddToFavorites(this.youtubeVideo);
}

class MasterRemoveFromHistory extends MasterEvents {
  final int index;

  MasterRemoveFromHistory(this.index);
}

class MasterRemoveFromFavorites extends MasterEvents {
  final int index;

  MasterRemoveFromFavorites(this.index);
}
```

Comment: could you also share the code inside bloc?

Comment: added the code inside the Bloc files, thanks!

Comment: what if instead of two separate states for adding and removing, you had one and bloc for that state would checkin the list if the object is already there, if it is, remove it from the list and if it's not, add it to the list.

Comment: Yes i´ve been thinking on it but I cannot find the way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So one way to perform a toggle is to replace Add and Remove event with just one. So you could get rid of these events:

```
class MasterAddToFavorites extends MasterEvents {
  final YoutubeVideo youtubeVideo;

  MasterAddToFavorites(this.youtubeVideo);
}

class MasterRemoveFromFavorites extends MasterEvents {
  final int index;

  MasterRemoveFromFavorites(this.index);
}
```

and replace it with:

```
class MasterToggleInFavorites extends MasterEvents {
  final YoutubeVideo video;

  MasterToggleInFavorites(video);
}
```

Next, inside of bloc, inside of method that handles that event, you could do something like this:

```
Stream<MasterState> _toggleInFavorites(MasterToggleInFavorites event) async* {
    final int index = this
        .state
        .favorites
        .indexWhere((item) => item.videoId == event.youtubeVideo.videoId);

    if (index == -1) {
      final favorites = List<YoutubeVideo>.from(this.state.favorites);
      favorites.add(event.youtubeVideo);
      event.youtubeVideo.isFavourite = true;

      yield this.state.copyWith(favorites: favorites);
    } else {
      final favorites = List<YoutubeVideo>.from(this.state.favorites);
      favorites.removeAt(index);
      event.youtubeVideo.isFavourite = false;

      yield this.state.copyWith(favorites: favorites);
    }
```

Comment: It worked perfect. But stil l cannot reflect the change in the icons to show the color depending on the toggled change.

Comment: try creating some kind of wrapper class that would inside have two fields: video and a bool if it is favourite or not.

Comment: I´ve added the class above and the button, in case yo can see the code. For any reason I´m missing something as it is not reflecting the color change. I´m new to flutter so please bear with me if this is a noob question.

Comment: Yes, I know, this is what I cannot achieve. It may look simple but Im getting crazy with it, becausse 've tried many different ways and stucked on it. thanks so much!

Comment: I've updated my post, take a look at _toggleInFavorites method

Comment: Thanks, now it reflects the changes in the new item placed as favorite in the new List, but not changing the refreshing state automatically. Is there any other way rather than changing to StatefulWidget and using setstate to hear the change/refresh? Thanks once again. It is being really helpful your advise

Answer (score 0):

Video Class

```
class YoutubeVideo {
  final String videoId, title, description, banner;
  bool isFavorite;

  YoutubeVideo(
      {@required this.videoId,
      @required this.title,
      @required this.description,
      @required this.banner,
      this.isFavorite = false});

  factory YoutubeVideo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json,
      {bool fromPlayList = false}) {
    final snippet = json['snippet'];
    final thumbnail =
        snippet['thumbnails']['standard'] ?? snippet['thumbnails']['high'];

    String videoId;

    if (!fromPlayList) {
      videoId = json['contentDetails']['videoId'];
    } else {
      videoId = snippet['resourceId']['videoId'];
    }

    return YoutubeVideo(
        videoId: videoId,
        title: snippet['title'],
        description: snippet['description'],
        banner: thumbnail['url']);
  }
}
```

And here is the action onPressed but for any reason is not reflecting the color change

```
CupertinoButton(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        minSize: 30,
                        onPressed: () {
                          masterBloc.add(MasterToggleInFavorites(item));
                        },
                        child: CircleContainer(
                          child: Icon(
                            //Icons.playlist_add,
                            item.isFavorite
                                ? Icons.favorite_border
                                : Icons.favorite,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          size: 35,
                        ),
                      ),
```

Comment: all is left for you to do is to set the `isFavorite` bool on the YoutubeVideo when you press the button.